# Check filter defined or not?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters, automatic-updates

Is this possible to find out whether `add_filter( 'allow_major_auto_core_updates', '__return_true', 1 );` already added or not in some other plugin?

or

can i check this automatic updates set for particular WordPress site ?

if they defined automatic updates settings via constant then we can get it from via

```
if(defined ('constant') ){
//code here
}
```

if they use filters, how to find it out?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question, but I think installing the debug bar with the hooks and filters plugin could help you.

- [Debugbar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/)
- [Actions and filters addon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-actions-and-filters-addon/)

Answer (score 1):

[`has_filter()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_filter) checks if any filter has been registered for a hook.

This is what I want really